# Autolayout and iPhone 6 / 6 Plus misplacements

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, iphone-6

This is strange and I don't find the cause... I have a view inside of another view, and I've set constraints for the child view to leading, top, trailing and bottom spaces to its parent view. I see this view correctly in iPhone 5, but in iPhone 6 the inner view does not keep the trailing constraint and "goes partially out" of the screen... why could thi be happening?

**EDIT:** This is the view configuration in storyboard:

[image]

the view at the back is a `UIImageView` that I've pin to leading, top, trailing and bottom of the superview. The interesting thing id the container: there I embed another view controller with its own view. Such view seems to take the room of the container when I run in iPhone 5, but in iPhone 6 the content of such container goes partially away to the right side of the screen...

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your constraints so we can understand your setup.

Comment: @SteveWilford Done, I hope this explains better my scenario...

Comment: You don't have leading or trailing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Center-X and Proportional width constraints and replace with leading and trailing constraints.

Comment: I also believe it is this reason--cause iphone 6's width is larger and forcing the display to be wider than it should be. but the only thing you may have to dynamically adjust is the constant of leading and trailing constraints